# How do I summarize hashes within a hash?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a hash like this:

```
Some_hash =
    {"Albania"=>"Europe", 
    "Andorra"=>"Europe", 
    "Austria"=>"Europe",
    Lebanon"=>"Asia", 
    "Macau"=>"Asia", 
    "Malaysia"=>"Asia",
    "Papua New Guinea"=>"Asia",
    "Jamaica"=>"North America",
    "Martinique"=>"North America",
    "Argentina"=>"South America",
    "Chile"=>"South America", 
    "Sao Tome and Principe"=>"Africa", 
    "Senegal"=>"Africa",
    "Somalia"=>"Africa",}
```

I would like to identify the five continents individually, and the countries that belong to them, such that I end up with something like this:

```
{"Africa" => ["Senegal", "Somalia"]}
{"Europe" => ["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria"]}
```

for all of the continents.

I tried this:

```
def country
  inflation_hash = {}
  XPath.match( data, "//country").map do |element|
    inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["continent"]
  end
  inflation_hash.each do |country, continent|
    new_hash = {}
    if inflation_hash.has_value?("Africa") == true
      new_hash["Africa"] = inflation_hash.keys
      puts new_hash
    end
  end
end
```

and it works much too well. I get a new hash:

```
{Africa => []}
```

but I have two problems:

1. I create a new hash for each African country.
2. Each new hash contains all the keys, which includes all non-African countries.

I think the first problem has to do with the `each` method so I have to set some conditional, right?

The second problem, I have no idea how to fix.

Any pointers would be greater appreciated.

Comment: check inflation_hash contains "Africa"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost don't use upper-case letters for variables in Ruby as you did with `SomeHash` and `XPath`. When a variable name starts with an upper-case letter, it means it's a constant and you probably didn't want it to be a constant.

`each` is not the best way to do this, you can do this much more simply with `inject` as in:

```
countries = {
    "Albania"=>"Europe", 
    "Andorra"=>"Europe", 
    "Austria"=>"Europe",
    "Lebanon"=>"Asia", 
    "Macau"=>"Asia", 
    "Malaysia"=>"Asia",
    "Papua New Guinea"=>"Asia",
    "Jamaica"=>"North America",
    "Martinique"=>"North America",
    "Argentina"=>"South America",
    "Chile"=>"South America", 
    "Sao Tome and Principe"=>"Africa", 
    "Senegal"=>"Africa",
    "Somalia"=>"Africa"}

by_continents = countries.inject({}) do |memo, (k,v)|
  memo[v] ||= []
  memo[v] << k
  memo
end
```

The output for this is:

```
{"Europe"=>["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria"], "Asia"=>["Lebanon", "Macau", "Malaysia", "Papua New Guinea"], "North America"=>["Jamaica", "Martinique"], "South America"=>["Argentina", "Chile"], "Africa"=>["Sao Tome and Principe", "Senegal", "Somalia"]}
```

You have all countries grouped by continent and you can pick any one of them.

In your code it should be placed like this:

```
def country
  inflation_hash = {}
  XPath.match( data, "//country").map do |element|
    inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["continent"]
  end
  by_continents = inflation_hash.inject({}) do |memo, (k,v)|
    memo[v] ||= []
    memo[v] << k
    memo
  end
  puts by_continents.inspect
  by_continents
end
```

Comment: You could do it more easily than `inject` using `each_with_object`: `countries.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), memo|`, and remove the final `memo` in the block.

Comment: @theTinMan 's suggestion could be combined with a hash creation that has an empty array as the default value: `countries.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) {|(k,v),memo| memo[v] << k}`.

Comment: Mauricio: thank you for your feedback. Would really like to use your method but unfortunately, it only returns one continent and one country: {"Europe"=>["Albania"]}. 

@theTinMan: I am working on trying out your method right now. Will let you know how it goes. Thank you everyone for your suggestions! Its all about fine running it now.

Comment: @MsUzoAgu you probably replaced it the wrong way, check the answer again and use it the way I have included it.

Comment: hi Mauricio: it works! Thank you so much:) … 

I want to understand why it didn't work first time so will review that code; and this too so I know how to use it next time. 

On the other hand, do you have any resources that explain the inject method very well? Looked in RobyDoc and didn't find anything under hash-class for it; did find something in methods but have a hard time understanding what we programmers mean when we refer to Enumerable. Thank you once again:)

I am new to Ruby (programming in general; started about 2 months ago) so any resource will be awesome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: The real issue was `new_hash = {}` inside the `each` block. Since it wasn't being created out of it, you were only seeing the last value that was produced and not accumulating the values. If you move it to before calling the `each` method you almost have a solution, but you still wouldn't accumulate the country names. You can see `inject` docs here -> http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem:

---

```
def sort_by_continents
  # Initialize example Hash of countries:
  country_map = {"Albania"=>"Europe", "Andorra"=>"Europe",
                 "Lebanon"=>"Asia", "Macau"=>"Asia",
                 "Jamaica"=>"North America", "Chile"=>"South America",
                 "Senegal"=>"Africa", "Malaysia"=>"Asia"}

  # Create a new Hash where initial values are = []
  continent_map = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}

  # For each country in the initial hash:
  #   Add the corresponding country to the appropriate continent.
  country_map.each {|country,continent| continent_map[continent] << country}

  # Return the continent map.
  continent_map
end
```

---

Memoization is definitely the best and most efficient approach (as seen above), but for a beginner, I'd say start with something that makes sense. The memoization and optimization will come once you've spent more time with Ruby - I know when I started, the notion of `inject` and `||=` were incredibly confusing. Starting at the basics is always the best approach.

Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for explaining and breaking things down! Appreciate it:)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this at the same as you're building `inflation_hash`, just use a [`default_proc` on the Hash to auto-vivify](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) new elements as empty arrays:

```
inflation_hash = { }
new_hash       = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
XPath.match(data, "//country").map do |element|
  name, continent = element.attributes.values_at('name', 'continent')
  inflation_hash[name] = continent
  new_hash[continent].push(name)
end
```

That will leave you with `inflation_hash` as you currently have it and `new_hash` like:

```
{
  "Africa" => ["Senegal", "Somalia"],
  "Europe" => ["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi mu is too short! I follow your code till the end. I need to find a way to let Ruby know not to create a new array each time it encounters a continent - I only want it to create 5 hashes since I have 5 unique keys for continent. Working on some revision and will let you know how it goes. Thank you very much for replying:)

Comment: Why create five hashes (each with a single key and value) when a single hash will do? If you really do need an array of five single-key hashes then you could `aoh = h.map { |k, v| { k => v } }` to build it. And a little more reading on how `default_proc` works might be useful.

Comment: Hi mu is too short! You are right, one hash will do! I am new to programming (started learning 2 months ago) so didn't think to approach the problem that way. I will try out your code again and let you know how it works. 

On the other hand, I would appreciate your pointing me to any resource that will explain proc in a very simple manner. I will keep looking too (so amazed at how much there is to learn … but I love learning how to program so not complaining at all). 

Once again, thank you. Will let you know how your code works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a hash already, therefore why not do what you need inplace:

```
countries.keys.each { |k| 
  (countries[countries.delete(k)] ||= []) << k
}
```

This will fail if you have countries named exactly as continents, but it is not your case, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways I would consider:

```
version1 = countries.each_with_object({}) do |(key,value),result|
 (result[value] ||= []) << key
end

version2 = Hash[countries.group_by(&:last).map{|x,y|[x,y.map(&:first)]}]
```